# Example view for TableTree control for SAP Fiori app

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

is there an example for using TableTree control in SAP Fiori app. I have an OData service already defined with the association. How do I use it in my view?

Below is the view snippet:

```
                     <table:TreeTable rows="{/Zbpo_Cds_Fkkvp}"
                            selectionMode="None"
                            visibleRowCount="11"
                            showColumnVisibilityMenu="true"
                            enableCellFilter="true"
                            enableColumnReordering="false"
                            class="sapUiSizeCompact"
                            expandFirstLevel="true"
                                >
                            <table:columns>
                           <table:Column>
                            <Text label = "Contract Partner" text ="{gpart}"></Text>
                             </table:Column>
                             <!--<table:Column>
                             <Text text ="{vkont}"> </Text>
                             </table:Column>-->

                            </table:columns>
                        </table:TreeTable>
```

I have following error:
Neither navigation paths parameters, nor (complete/valid) tree hierarchy annotations where provided to the TreeBinding.

Do i need to annotate my CDS view?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

would this example be useful for you? 
http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2015/10/23/treetable-odata-binding

kind regards,
Gabriel

Comment: I did check this example. What i fail to understand is how do you use the Treetable in your view? Also, the implementation explained in this example is already generated. I can get a normal table working in my view by defining the a reference to OData service.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a view using HIERARCHY statement in hdbview, not in CDS, etc. like this:

```
VIEW "myview" 
AS SELECT
    "HIERARCHY_RANK" ,
    "HIERARCHY_PARENT_RANK" ,
    HIERARCHY_LEVEL - 1 AS "HIERARCHY_LEVEL" ,
    *
FROM
    HIERARCHY ( SOURCE (
    SELECT
        ID AS node_id,
        PARENT_ID AS parent_id,
        *
    FROM
        "mytable" ) )
```

then reference this view in your xsoadata definition.